# Get the address of a dynamic range from a validation formula

Tags: validation, vba, excel

My code sets list validation on a cell using the range given by an `OFFSET` formula that depends on that cell's address.

Because this validation gets set programmatically on cells that already have contents, I want a function to determine whether the existing contents of the cell violate validation.

I ran into problems testing this, using the following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim formula As String
    Dim rangeName As String
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With sht
        .Range("a1").Value = "a"
        .Range("a2").Value = "aa"
        Set rng = .Range("b1")
        formula = "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1,2,1)"
        rng.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=formula
        rangeName = Replace(formula, "=", "")
        Set ResultRange = .Range(rangeName).Find(rng.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If ResultRange Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "violates validation"
        Else
            Debug.Print "validated"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This test should assign drop-down validation to cell `B1` with the contents of cells `A1` and `A2`, then check whether or not `B1`'s contents match either of those cells.  But it fails at the `Set ResultRange` line with this error:

`Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.`

I think the problem is that when I call `Range(rangeName)`, Excel doesn't know which cell to apply the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` to, so I need to somehow calculate the address that `formula` resolves to for this cell--in this case, `$A$1:$A$2`, so that I can assign that value to `RangeName`.

So, given this `OFFSET()` formula that I'm passing dynamic parameters to, how do I get the range that this formula returns for the range specified by `rng`?

EDIT: As the formula may change depending on different circumstances, I'm looking for a solution that, given an `OFFSET()` formula starting at a certain range, returns the range given by that formula.  A hard-coded solution would not be acceptable, as there are several different `OFFSET()` formulas like this in the sheet and it will be impractical to change the code of the validation test every time one of the formulas changes.

Comment: So... will the offset formula be calculated via code or hard coded as a string in your hypothetical working situation?

Comment: @DanielCook, the offset formula is hard coded as a named range.

Comment: I'm just trying to clearly understand... so you are saying that in the actual use case your formula instead of being something like `"=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,-1,2,1)"` it will be something like `"=NamedRange"`? What I specifically want to clarify is if you're expecting things like `=OFFSET(A1,2,3,B1,B2)` or if the numbers will be hardcoded.

Comment: @DanielCook: The column and row offsets will be hard coded, as in the OFFSET(INDIRECT(...)) example you just gave.  Again, though, there are several different OFFSET() formulas in the application, so the most practical solution would be a function ReturnRange(initialRange as Range,offsetFormula as String) that returns the range calculated for that cell and formula.

Comment: That's what I thought. And I agree with you, I just wanted to clarify before I wrote that for you. But... since you clarified I expanded your function header snippet into a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but will do what you like you must have already defined `rng`, and `rng` must not be in column A:

```
rangeName = .Range(.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column - 1), .Cells(rng.Row + 1, rng.Column - 1)).Address
```

As another note, your validation will by default ignore blanks so you may want to update your if to check for blanks:

```
If ResultRange Is Nothing And rng.Value <> "" then
    Debug.Print "violates validation"
Else
    Debug.Print "validated"
End If
```

EDIT as requested, I went ahead and made the OffsetFormula optional because it will assume the passed range has the formula that needs parsed:

```
Function ReturnRange(initialRange As Range, Optional OffsetFormula As String) As Range
    Dim parameters
    Dim upBound As Long
    Dim topLeftCell As Range
    Dim bottomRightCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    'If an error occurs result will be Nothing
    If OffsetFormula = "" Then OffsetFormula = initialRange.Formula
    If UCase(Left(OffsetFormula, 7)) = "=OFFSET" Then
        parameters = Split(Left(OffsetFormula, Len(OffsetFormula) - 1), ",")
        'Using upbound variable to avoid constant calls to Ubound(parameters)
        upBound = UBound(parameters)
        Set topLeftCell = initialRange.Offset(parameters(upBound - 3), parameters(upBound - 2))
        Set bottomRightCell = topLeftCell.Offset(parameters(upBound - 1) - 1, parameters(upBound) - 1)
        Set ReturnRange = Range(topLeftCell, bottomRightCell)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would require that I change this line of code whenever I change the `OFFSET()` formula.  I need something that isn't hard-coded; I'll modify my question accordingly.